# How can I create a test object of a specific GUI class with the class determined at test runtime?

Tags: vbscript, qtp

The idea is to have a GUI class name (like `JavaRadioButton`) in a string variable, and instantiate a test object of that type using a `Description` object. Like in:

```
Dim Descr: Set Descr=Description.Create
Descr.Add "property1", "value"
Descr.Add "property2", "value"
Descr.Add "property3", "value"
Dim MyTO: Set MyTO=JavaRadioButton (Descr)
```

***but*** with the GUI class (`JavaRadioButton` in this case) being parameterized, i.e. I have the string `"JavaRadioButton"` in a variable and want to create a testobject of the GUI class that is contained in that variable.

An obvious attempt is to use the `"micclass"` property, which reports the GUI class name of a test object:

```
Dim ClassName: ClassName="JavaRadioButton"
Dim Descr: Set Descr=Description.Create
Descr.Add "property1", "value"
Descr.Add "property2", "value"
Descr.Add "property3", "value"
Descr.Add "micclass", ClassName
Dim MyTO: Set MyTO=JavaObject (Descr)
```

However, afterwards `MyTO` still is just a `JavaObject`. For example, it does not support the `.Set` method as a `JavaRadioButton` would.

My current "solution" would be to construct a string that contains the assignment, and evaluate this using `ExecuteGlobal` (or `Eval`, as shown here):

```
Dim ClassName: ClassName="JavaRadioButton"
Dim Descr: Set Descr=Description.Create
Descr.Add "property1", "value"
Descr.Add "property2", "value"
Descr.Add "property3", "value"
Descr.Add "micclass", ClassName
Dim MyTO: Set MyTO=Eval (ClassName & "(Descr)")
```

This seems to work, as long as `ClassName` and `Descr` are reachable for `Eval`, which sometimes is clumsy to achieve. And it requires error handling code, if you want to catch errors.

**Isn´t there a way to do this without creating a string containing sourcecode, and executing it?**

Note I added the VBScript tag because that´s QTP´s scripting language, however this question is QTP-specific.

Comment: Tried that with `WebElement` a while ago and drew the same conclusions: A generic stays a generic type and does not magically cast into another type. Did you consider a `Select Case` to determine the class name and to construct and return an object of this class? The amount of micclasses is limited, so that must be doable.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Yeah, I thought about that. But I hate Code like that that just permutates types and is otherwise identical in all cases. So I'll stick to the Eval () (or really: ExecuteGlobal) variant, and keep looking for new alternatives to that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty easy to achieve if you're willing to use `ChildObjects` rather than regular descriptive programming.

```
Function GetObj(parent, micClass, desc)
    desc.Add "micclass", micClass
    Set children = parent.ChildObjects(desc)
    If children.Count < 1 Then
        Err.Raise 1, "GetObj", "Object not found"
    ElseIf children.Count > 1 Then
        Err.Raise 1, "GetObj", "Description is not unique, found " & children.Count & " matches"
    End If
    Set GetObj = children(0)
End Function
```

Usage:

```
GetObj(oPage, "WebEdit", desc).Set "Set is a specific method"
```

I don't know how much value this gives you since you still need to have `Set` as part of the script and not as a string...

Comment: Really nice twist. I could create "template" objects (one for each GUI type) in the OR and retrieve the one needed (depending on the class name) using ChildObjects. The resulting test object will be of the correct type. In fact, that is what I need. Thanks.

Comment: The playback method call problem is solveable: I could create a common base of playback functions and register them all with the GUI classes I need. Then, calling GetObj (..).MyFunc will succeed as long as the GUI class has RegisterUserFunc´d such a function. (This is "very late binding", or even "too late binding". VBScript does not care what the object type is if the method call can be dispatched at runtime. No base type required (as would be in Java, or other OOP languages).

Comment: But!!! One problem would be the fact that the items returned by ChildObjects always return true in Exist, making it impossible to wait for (for example) their disappearance. Thus I´ll stick to the generate-code-and-execute-it-at-runtime solution.

Comment: If you want to wait for the object to disappear, you could re-run the function at the point you would otherwise call `Exist`. Obviously you would have to change it to not fail when no objects are found but return `Nothing` instead.

Comment: Yeah. But it´s just that a function receives an optional test object. If the function should use it, the argument value is not empty, otherwise empty. That SHOULD be possible. Indeed, it is, I just check for IsEmpty for the test object argument. And it works fine. But it generates the warning if the Rec Scenario is active. That´s what the question is all about.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have QTP at hand, but you could try something like this were I launch the assumption that the objects are actually functions that return an object with the same name of that function.

```
Dim ClassName: ClassName="JavaRadioButton"
Dim Descr: Set Descr=Description.Create
Descr.Add "property1", "value"
Descr.Add "property2", "value"
Descr.Add "property3", "value"
Descr.Add "micclass", ClassName

Dim constructor : Set constructor = GetRef(ClassName)
Dim MyTO: Set MyTO=constructor(Descr)
```

Could you try that and let me know what it is doing? I am seriously curious.

---

*EDIT*

Basis for the assumption: The JavaScriptButton is a function that returns an object. The function can support arguments. This is a way to implement a builder or even an abstract factory pattern:

```
Option explicit    

Class Duck

    Private sound_
    Public Name      ' public field, refactor to property

    Public Function Init(n, sound)
        sound_ = sound
        Name = n
        Set Init = me
    End Function

    Public Sub Quack()
        msgbox sound_
    End Sub

End Class


Public Function NormalDuck(name)
     Set NormalDuck = (new Duck).Init(name, "quack, quack")
End Function

Public Function RubberDuck(name)
     Set RubberDuck = (new Duck).Init(name, "squick, squick")
End Function

Public Function DecoyDuck(name)
     Set DecoyDuck = (new Duck).Init(name, "")
End Function

dim myDuck
dim duckBuilder
dim duckName, duckType

duckType = InputBox("What kind of duck do you want?", "DuckType", "NormalDuck")
Set duckBuilder = GetRef(duckType)

duckName = InputBox("What will be its name?", "DuckName", "Donald")
Set myDuck = duckBuilder(duckName)

myDuck.Quack
```

*Note: VBScript supports the `set o = (new foo).Init(bar)` construct, while the QTP "compiler" will return a syntax error. You'll have to split it into two statements in QTP*

Comment: "Ungültiger Prozeduraufruf oder ungültiges Argument: 'GetRef'", i.e. "Invalid call or invalid argument". There seems to be no global function called JavaRadioButton.
Test object classes are just that: Classes, like the ones created with Class...End Class, I think. What the construct `Set X=JavaRadioButton (Y)` syntactically is appears like dark fog to me. Parameterized constructor call? Not possible in VBScript, I though. Scope and visibility indicate that the classes are not defined in VBScript, but injected via COM, or so.

Comment: Above statements are acknowledged by the fact that the debugger does not know about JavaRadioButton as a global identifier (create a watch on it -> error). I estimate the hook into the VBScript engine in some way and implement this custom (i.e. non-Standard, non-VBScript) syntax that way.

Comment: @TheBlastOne Well, normally I create Public Functions to a class VBScript so I can provide a constructor for it. That function can be refered to with GetRef. I will provide an example in the answer.